# Append html to state variable in ReactJS with ternary condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am checking if a string is empty and if it isn't I want to append some html to it as well. However, what I tried seems to turn the whole statement into a string instead of wrapping it inside a div. Below are the two methods I've tried.

```
var myVar = this.state.myString == '' ? '': '<div>'+this.state.myString+'</div>';
return(
   {myVar}
);

var myVar = this.state.myString == '' ? '': {'<div>'+this.state.myString+'</div>'};
return(
   <div className="container">
       {myVar}
   </div>
);
```

I only want to display something if it exists.

I tried just returning the state then wrap it inside the html tags in the return(); but for buttons it shows a grey blob with bootstraps .btn class.

Comment: Interesting. I will say that when comparing something to a falsy value, you don't need the '=='. The same thing could be written as

Comment: You say you want to append.. what is the original value, and what is the desired result? You dont append anything in the provided example..

Comment: var myVar = this.state.myString ? 'div' + this.state.homeTeamRuns + 'div' : '';

Comment: Also, what data type is stored in homeTeamRuns? is it a string?

Comment: Edited for clarity. Yes homeTeamRuns is just a string

Comment: Thank you @DustinStiles that cleaned up my code

Comment: Ah, I see you changed the props, haha. So now we are getting closer. You still aren't appending anything if it does exist, just replacing

Comment: For that you can do it this way

Comment: var myVar = this.state.myString;
var result = myVar ? myVar += ('div' + this.state.homeTeamRuns + 'div') : '';

Comment: I split it up into two different variables to make the ternary slightly less verbose. Then, pass the result variable to the render method

Comment: Thanks @DustinStiles but, with this method how would I add classes to it? Do I not need to wrap the divs inside the arrows? i.e. '<div>'?

Comment: Oh shoot! Haha yes, you absolutely do! that was my mistake :p

Comment: That seems to still return the whole section as a string and does not wrap it inside the tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating jsx elements, you're not creating strings, you're creating functions (under the hood). Between jsx elements you bind data between curly braces

```
var someElement = <div>{ this.state.myString }</div>
```

Then inside render:

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>{ someElement }</div>
  )
}
```

If you want to conditionally display some element, you can do this directly in jsx:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.myString !== '' && // if string is not empty add this div
      <div>{ this.state.myString }</div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Boolean values do not appear in jsx, so if `this.state.myString !== ''` is false, nothing will be displayed. Often you see truthy/falsey values converted to boolean with doublebangs--so this works too:

```
{ !!this.state.myString && <div>{ this.state.myString }</div> }
```